# ofstream not recognized by g++?

Tags: c++, g++, ofstream

The following C++ ofstream code runs on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

```
std::ofstream xyz_file;
xyz_file.open(movie_name, std::ios_base::app);
```

But when it is compiled using G++, it gives the following error message:

```
dynamics.cpp: In member function 'void dynamics::add_movie_frame(std::string)':
dynamics.cpp:142: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/fstream:696: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to enable c++11 support with `-std=c++11`. I'm looking for duplicates.

Comment: g++ "-std=c++0x"  ...
works, thanks!